# How to see if all data structures dependencies are solved?

Tags: c++, boost, dependencies, dependency-properties

Lets imagine demo situation that we have such simple structure

```
struct service
{
 std::string name
 std::set<std::string> depends_on_service_name;
};
```

We have some raw data (text file, io stream or what ewer) coming into our `parser` that turns it into `service struct` instances and puts them into `std::map<service> services` we need a way to chack if all map items have all there `depends_on_service_name` resolved (meaning there shall be `services[item].name` in map for each `service[other_item].depends_on_service_name`). Is there any standart way to check for such things in boost of manual `for_each` is the way to go each time `parser` appends new item(s) into map?

Answer (score 0):

The "way to go" here is to solve this problem during input verification and abstraction. You are representing a directed (probably acyclic) graph with the service map, and you should represent it as such (e.g. using Boost.Graph) instead of rolling your own graph structure with sets and maps. While you are building this explicit graph structure, missing services will naturally be discovered.

Comment: could you please share with us some more info such as: how service implementation, and services signature shall look in case of BG use, also if you can please provide simple code demo of what do you mean.

Comment: @myWallJSON: Sorry, but you can't provide enough details in your question to make it sufficiently precise for code. The code you have shown is simply a node in a directed graph, nothing more.